# Unable to create sharepoint site from migrated site template(.wsp)

Tags: sharepoint

I have subsite (sharepoint2010) which consist of some custom feature and which has been migrated from sharepoint 2007, I save this site as a site template (in dev environment), when I try to create a site base on that site template in production (it is havig all the updated solution) it was not able to create the site,I check the log and found the following error:

> No document templates uploaded for list "$Resources:core,MasterPageGallery;" -- none
>       found for list template "100"
>
> The logs  are written below against the correlation ID
>       and Failed to apply template "STS#1" to web at URL
>
> Failed to activate site-scoped features for template 'STS#1' in site
>
> 0x1A7C SharePoint Foundation Feature Infrastructure 889y High The element of type
>      'Module' for feature '1324A_Test_NLModules' (id: cd6559bc-d107-4609-baa2-c0582c63351b)
>       threw an exception during activation:
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020009):
>
> where '1324A_Test_NL  the name of the template.

Although I can create site based on the same template on my development environment.

I have already activated the the `PublishingInfrastructure` feature, in my site collection features gallery and deleted unnecessary document from one of the document library in the site. Can anyone suggest what will be the resolution?